# How to keep the header and trailer while zlib decompress and compress

Tags: python, zlib

I have raw data extracted from PDF and I decompressed the raw data and compressed it again.

I expected the same header and trailer, but the header was changed.

- Original Hex Header

```
48 89 EC 57 ....
```

- Converted Hex Header

```
78 9C EC BD ...
```

I dug into zlib compression and got header `48` also is one of zlib.header.

But mostly `78` is used for zlib compression.

It's my code which decompress and compress:

```
decompress_wbit = 12
compress_variable = 6
output_data = zlib.decompress(open(raw_data, "rb").read(), decompress_wbit)
output_data = zlib.compress(output_data, 6)
output_file = open(raw_data + '_', "wb")
output_file.write(output_data)
output_file.close()
```

I changed the `decompress_wbit` and `compress_variable` but still keeps `78`.

So not sure how to get `48` as header.

Here is the short description about zlib.header.

- CINFO (bits 12-15)

Indicates the window size as a power of two, from 0 (256 bytes) to 7 (32768 bytes). This will usually be 7. Higher values are not allowed.

- CM (bits 8-11)

The compression method. Only Deflate (8) is allowed.

- FLEVEL (bits 6-7)

Roughly indicates the compression level, from 0 (fast/low) to 3 (slow/high)

- FDICT (bit 5)

Indicates whether a preset dictionary is used. This is usually 0. 1 is technically allowed, but I don't know of any Deflate formats that define preset dictionaries.

- FCHECK (bits 0-4)

A checksum (5 bits, 0..31), whose value is calculated such that the entire value divides 31 with no remainder.

Typically, only the CINFO and FLEVEL fields can be freely changed, and FCHECK must be calculated based on the final value.* Assuming no preset dictionary, there is no choice in what the other fields contain, so a total of 32 possible headers are valid. Here they are:

```
      FLEVEL: 0       1       2       3
CINFO:
     0      08 1D   08 5B   08 99   08 D7
     1      18 19   18 57   18 95   18 D3
     2      28 15   28 53   28 91   28 CF
     3      38 11   38 4F   38 8D   38 CB
     4      48 0D   48 4B   48 89   48 C7
     5      58 09   58 47   58 85   58 C3
     6      68 05   68 43   68 81   68 DE
     7      78 01   78 5E   78 9C   78 DA
```

Please let me know how to keep the zlib.header while decompression & compression

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will first note that it doesn't matter. The data will be decompressed fine with that zlib header. Why do you care?

You are giving `zlib.compress` a small amount of data that permits a smaller window. Since it is permitted, the Python library is electing to compress with a smaller window.

A way to avoid that would be to use `zlib.compressobj` instead. Upon initiation, it doesn't know how much data you will be feeding it and will default to the largest window size.